# Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_cells.range' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.sheets.v4.GridRange)

Tags: node.js, google-sheets

I'm trying to set the background of a single specific cell in column C via the NodeJS Google Sheets library. However, I am receiving this error

```
errors: [
    {
      message: `Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_cells.range' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.sheets.v4.GridRange), "'Question of the day'!C2"`,
      reason: 'invalid'
    }
  ]
```

This is my method call

```
      sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
        auth: this._token,
        spreadsheetId: this._spreadsheet,
        resource: {
          requests: [{
            updateCells: {
              range: '\'Question of the day\'!C' + (index + 1),
              fields: 'userEnteredFormat',
              rows: [{
                values: [{
                  userEnteredFormat: {
                    backgroundColor: {
                      red: 1,
                      green: 0,
                      blue: 0
                    }
                  }
                }]
              }]
            }
          }]
        }
      })
```

The auth is correct as well as the spreadsheet. I tested the range the error throws in Google Sheets and it's a valid and working range.

I'm not sure why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, the UpdateCellsRequest of batchUpdate method is used. In this case, the range is the gridRange which is not A1Notation. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

#### Modified script:

In this case, please use the sheet ID of the sheet of "Question of the day" to `gridRange`.

```js
const gridRange = {
  "sheetId": 0, // Please set the sheet ID of the sheet of "Question of the day".
  "startRowIndex": index,
  "endRowIndex": index + 1,
  "startColumnIndex": 2, // This means the column "C"
  "endColumnIndex": 3 // This means the column "C"
};
sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
  auth: this._token,
  spreadsheetId: this._spreadsheet,
  resource: {
    requests: [{
      updateCells: {
        range: gridRange,
        fields: 'userEnteredFormat',
        rows: [{
          values: [{
            userEnteredFormat: {
              backgroundColor: {
                red: 1,
                green: 0,
                blue: 0
              }
            }
          }]
        }]
      }
    }]
  }
})
```

#### References:

- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)